# Image animation with clip-path

Tags: css, css-transitions

Here is a demo of my problem :
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sb4bk0xg/2/)

I have two `absolute` images and each of them animates `clip-path`. While `second` comes after `first` in the `DOM` I can see the `hover` animation. But I cant see the `hover` animation of `first`. So my idea was that whenever I hover `first` I also `hover` `second` by the amount `first` hovers.
So basically:

- `hover first` --> expand `clip-path` of `first` --> shrink `clip-path` of `second`
- `hover second` --> expand `clip-path` of `second` --> shrink `clip-path` of `first`

So far I tried the `+ connector`, so for example:

```
.first:hover + .second {
}
```

But this will animate the `second` if I hover the `first`, so this does not help.
Any Ideas?

Comment: You need to adjust the clip-path of second when hovering first because it's covering the first image - https://jsfiddle.net/xdyjauwL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is right:

```
.first:hover + .second {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 90% 0, 50% 100%, 100% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 90% 0, 50% 100%, 100% 100%);
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sb4bk0xg/3/